# Pointers in CvSeq Finger Detection

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv

I am working on C++ openCv, were I want to detect the contours and defects and hull of human hand. I get something wrong when I convert from CvSeq to CvPoint, it always prints out the address's not the value of the sequence itself,
and it doesn't accept *(Defects[2].x). So, I want to print the values to know if am right or wrong and how to access them later ? please, thanks in advance.

Comment: The Code:For example:
CvSeq* CloneContour7=defects; 
CvPoint* Defects = new CvPoint[CloneContour7-> total]; 
cout <<  "The Defects";
for( int i=1; i<=CloneContour7-> total; i++ )
{  
 CvPoint* p= CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM( CvPoint, CloneContour7, i ); 
 Defects[i] = *p;
}
cout << '\n';
cout  << CloneContour7-> total;
cout << Defects[2].x; 
cout << '\n';
cout << Defects[2].x;
cout << '\n';  
Also to int*:
CvSeq* CloneContour8=hull; 
int* H = new int[CloneContour8-> total]; 
for( int i=1; i<=CloneContour8-> total; i++ )
{  
 int* x= CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM( int, CloneContour8, i ); 
 H[i] = *x;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
int *point = &seq;
cout << *point;
```

Comment: I know it is logically correct but I don't know why it makes error when I equalize  it this way, so I tried this out CvPoint* point2;       point2= (CvPoint*)(&CloneContour7[i]); cout <<  *point2; // but the cout with a pointer doesn't work it says no operator matches these   operands... and I don't know if am wrong or right. thanks @DragonClaw